# Clear a textbox only if a statement is true - PHP

Tags: php, textbox

I a have page in which users will be adding folders to their account. When they create a name for the album, it checks to see if an album of that name already exists; if it does already exists, it tells them it is taken, but if it doesn't, it creates the album which appears on the page.

What I need is for the textbox to reset ONLY if the album is created successfully. At the moment I have something similar to:

```
if(isset($_POST['create_album']))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['new_album']) && $_POST['new_album'] != "")
        {
            $new_album_name = $_POST['new_album'];
            if(/** Here I check if the $new_album_name exists **/) {        
                $new_album_name_error =  "album exists numbnuts";
            }
            else
            {
                            /** LOTS OF CODE **/
                /** Here I create a new album with the input **/
                            /** END OF LOTS OF CODE **/

                echo "<script> 
                    document.getElementById('new_album').value='';
                    </script>";

            }
        }
    }
```

The id of the submit button being 'create_album' and the id of the textbox being 'new_album'.

However I cannot seem to get anything to work, where it will get the ID of the textbox and clear it. Everything else works perfectly.

Note: In the code, I have taken out the filepaths and code for checking if the album exists and for creating one, for simplicity and because it's not needed.

Comment: What is this `if($new_album_name exists)` ??? And this `create new album;` ???

Comment: @Tomás I have just taken out the code which is showing the filepath for simplicity.

Comment: Obviously it is `php6` xD

Comment: @Cthulhu you actually made me laugh. :D

Comment: @CraigJones do that with comments next time :p also, I'm not sure what you're doing with that script echo there, but I don't think you understand that PHP doesn't work in real-time, it gets a response from the server and then echos. After refreshing the page, the new value shouldn't even be in the text box unless you explicitly put a value back in there, unless you're using AJAX, in which case *that* is what should be taking care of it.

Comment: @CraigJones use comments `/* */` `//` to indicate removed/extraneous code

Comment: use ajax and jquery for easily handle this

Comment: if you call this using ajax, the js won't work since it's in a different document. you need to use that js in ajax call's callback function to create the desired effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is doing it without AJAX.

*NOTE: I'm supposing you are making the request to the same PHP file.*

```
<?php    
$new_album_name_error = "";
$albumName = "";
if(isset($_POST['create_album'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['new_album']) && $_POST['new_album'] != "") {
            $new_album_name = $_POST['new_album'];
            if(/** Here I check if the $new_album_name exists **/) {        
                $new_album_name_error =  "album exists numbnuts";
                $albumName = $new_album_name;
            }
            else {
                            /** LOTS OF CODE **/
                /** Here I create a new album with the input **/
                            /** END OF LOTS OF CODE **/

            }
    }
}

?>

<span class="error_code"><?php echo $new_album_name_error; ?></span>



<input type="text" id="new_album"><?php echo $albumName; ?></input>
```

Whenever you load the page, the input will be empty.

If some error appears, it will show the error in the `span` and it will display the album name.
If everything is OK, it will display the album name as empty.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a 1 time shot.  It queries server and spits out a response.  anything interactive needs some help. Id recommend jquery/javascript with ajax.  Have the submit button call an ajax page that does your query, it will return a result.  from that result you can determine the value of the textbox.

```
 <script>

 ($'#subAlbum').click (function ()
  {
       var newAlbum = $('#newAlbum');
       var data = "newAlbum="+newAlbum;
                        $.ajax(
                    {  
                            type: "POST",  
                            url: "checkAlbum.php",
                            data: data,
                            success: function(result)
                            {
                                   if (result == "true") //error condition
                                   {
                                      $('#newAlbum').val('');
                                   }
                                   else
                                   { 
                                      $('#newAlbum').val(newAlbum);
                                   }


                            }
                       })
  });


 </script>



 <form id='albumForm' method='POST' action='#'> 
 <input type='text' name='newAlbum' id='newAlbum' value='<?php echo $albumName;?>'>
 <input type='button' id='subAlbum' value='submit'>
```

on checkAlbum.php  run your query and echo either "true" or "false" as a response.